# Selecting a value from dropdown based on its index dynamically in selenium

Tags: vb.net, testing, selenium, automation

Is it possible to select a value of a drop down by its dynamic index that is returning from another function
whereas selectindex = 2 (generated dynamically)

selenium.Select(Id, "index = SelectIndex")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you can use `selenium.Select(id,"index = "+selectindex)` where selectIndex is a string which holds the dynamic value. If its an integer you need to convert it to a String